# Add a new row with editable textboxes in datagridview

Tags: c#, asp.net, datagridview

I am trying to add a new row to my data grid view and then take the information to insert into my database. 

 The problem with my code below is that it's creating a new empty row but is not letting me add anything in it. 
 I would like to be able to add something in it, then click on my button add that will add it to my table.

Method to fill the datagridview

```
  private void fillDataview()
    {
    OleDbCommand mycmdL = new OleDbCommand("SELECT UserID, FirstName, LastName, email, BoolAgent, BoolAdmin FROM Users WHERE (BoolAgent = true)", mycon);

    OleDbDataAdapter myadapt = new OleDbDataAdapter(mycmdL);
    myadapt.Fill(myset, "Users");
    DataTable tbAgent = myset.Tables["Users"];

    DataTable tbTemp = new DataTable();
    DataRow myrow = null;
    tbTemp = tbAgent.DefaultView.ToTable(true, "UserID", "FirstName", "LastName", "email");

    tbTemp.Columns["FirstName"].ColumnName = "FirstName";
    tbTemp.Columns["LastName"].ColumnName = "LastName";
    tbTemp.Columns["email"].ColumnName = "email";

    myrow = tbTemp.NewRow();
    myrow["FirstName"] = string.Empty;
    myrow["LastName"] = string.Empty;
    myrow["email"] = string.Empty;
    tbTemp.Rows.Add(myrow);

    ViewState["CurrentTable"] = tbTemp;
    GridView1.DataSource = tbTemp;
    GridView1.DataBind();  
}
```

I invoke this method in my button add:

```
private void addNewAgent()
{
    int row = 0;

    if (ViewState["CurrentTable"] !=null)
    {
        DataTable mydt = (DataTable)ViewState["CurrentTable"];
        DataRow myrow = null;

        if (mydt.Rows.Count>0)
        {
            for (int i = 1; i <= mydt.Rows.Count; i++)
            {
                Label id = GridView1.Rows[row].Cells[0].FindControl("lbl_ID") as Label;
                TextBox fn = GridView1.Rows[row].Cells[1].FindControl("txt_FirstName") as TextBox;
                TextBox ln = GridView1.Rows[row].Cells[2].FindControl("txt_LastName") as TextBox;
                TextBox email = GridView1.Rows[row].Cells[3].FindControl("txt_Email") as TextBox;

                myrow = mydt.NewRow();
                myrow["UserID"] = i + 1;
                mydt.Rows[i - 1]["FirstName"] = fn;
                mydt.Rows[i - 1]["LastName"] = fn;
                mydt.Rows[i - 1]["email"] = email;

                row++;
            }
            mydt.Rows.Add(myrow);
            ViewState["CurrentTable"] = mydt;
            GridView1.DataSource = mydt;
            GridView1.DataBind();             
        }
        else
        {
            Response.Write("view state is null"); 
        }
    }
    SetPreviousData();
}
```

My method setpreviousdata:

```
private void SetPreviousData()
{
    int row = 0;
    if (ViewState["CurrentTable"] != null)
    {
        DataTable dt = (DataTable)ViewState["CurrentTable"];
        if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < dt.Rows.Count; i++)
            {
               // Label id = GridView1.Rows[row].Cells[0].FindControl("lbl_ID") as Label;
                TextBox fn = GridView1.Rows[row].Cells[1].FindControl("txt_FirstName") as TextBox;
                TextBox ln = GridView1.Rows[row].Cells[2].FindControl("txt_LastName") as TextBox;
                TextBox email = GridView1.Rows[row].Cells[3].FindControl("txt_Email") as TextBox;

                fn.Text = dt.Rows[i]["FirstName"].ToString();
                ln.Text = dt.Rows[i]["LastName"].ToString();
                email.Text = dt.Rows[i]["email"].ToString();

                row++;
            }
        }
    } 
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to move this line of code and put it inside the for loop:

```
mydt.Rows.Add(myrow);
```

Otherwise, as it is right now, you are creating rows but only adding the last row.

Comment: Ok thanks! But I am only getting there when i click on my function. I should be able to add my information first then click on that button that will add everything t the table

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution. In the datagridview, the template field needs to be as a textbox.

```
 <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="FirstName">  
                <ItemTemplate>  
                    <asp:TextBox ID="txt_FirstName" runat="server"  Text='<%#Eval("FirstName") %>'></asp:TextBox>  
                </ItemTemplate>  
                <EditItemTemplate>  
                    <asp:TextBox ID="txt_FirstName" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("FirstName") %>'></asp:TextBox>  
                </EditItemTemplate>  
   </asp:TemplateField>
```